# angular How to load data from ngrx store instead of loading it from server

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

I am having the following code in my effects file

```
loadAllBooks$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(invokeBooksAPI),
    switchMap(() => {
         return this.bookService.get()
         .pipe(map((data) => booksFetchAPISuccess({ allBooks: data })))
       })
     )
    );
```

This loads data from the local json and here is the service call for the same

```
 get() {
    return this.httpClient.get<Book[]>('http://localhost:3000/books')
  }
```

Now what I need is I need to load the data from store instead of loading it from server and after 5 minutes I need to load it from server, is it possible to achieve that scenario.

I am using `npm i json-server` which runs locally on 3000 port where I did some modifications as per need

Here is the source code for the same I am working on

https://github.com/Github743/NgRxCRUD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a state for book as follows

```
export interface BookState {
    books: Book[],
    expired: boolean
}
```

and in the effects checking as follows for expired

```
loadAllBooks$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(invokeBooksAPI),
        withLatestFrom(this.appStore.select(isExpired)),
        tap(([action, isExpired]) => console.log(isExpired)),
        filter(([action, isExpired]) => isExpired),
        switchMap(() => {
            return this.bookService.get()
                .pipe(map((data) => booksFetchAPISuccess({ allBooks: data })
                ))
        }
        ),
    ),
);
```

Setting the expired property to true after success with a delay of 1 minute

```
booksFetchSuccess$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(booksFetchAPISuccess),
        delay(60000),
        map(() => {
            return resetBooks()
        })
    )
);
```

Action for the same

```
export const resetBooks = createAction(
    "[Books API] Reset Books in Store"
);
```

reducer for reset

```
on(resetBooks, (state) => {
        return {
            ...state,
            expired: true
        }
    }),
```

With this changes I am able to achieve as per required

Answer (score 0):

In order to read data from a store you use selectors. You can create a selector like this:

```
const getBooksFeatureState = createFeatureSelector<YourBookState>('books');

export const selectFeaturedBooks = createSelector(
  getBooksFeatureState ,
  state => state.featuredBooks
)

export const selectAllBooks = createSelector(
  getBooksFeatureState,
  state => state.allBooks
)
```

In this example I am retrieving all the books stored in a "featuredBooks" state in one selector and all the books in another selector. The featured state will return all the featured state of your books ( you might have several properties such as loading, selectedBook and so on )

However, bare in mind that the state is empty at the init of the app, it has to be filled with data at some point, it doesn't matter if you fetch your data at the beginning or you implement some kind of data cache. There are methods to create an ngrx cache.

This will depend on the approach you want to take, you might want to save your books in the localStorage and retrieve them to fill your store at the beginning ( that would require the use of an Effect to deal with the storage ). However, it's okay to retrieve the data from the server at the beginning and then update it whenever you need by dispatching the effect again later on.

Comment: Hi Osakr is it possible for you to add the same piece in my github code? I am new to Angular and NgRx just started exploring it and developed the code using a video tutorial